# S4HC Extensibility: SCBO_AUTHORIZATION/000: You are not authorized to create instance

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

I developed a side-by-side app using Java + SAP Cloud SDK (Neo). The app adds records to a custom business object.

The app was working fine when I concluded development in February. Now, I need to do some additional improvements, but I can add records anymore.

I am getting the error SCBO_AUTHORIZATION/000 - You are not authorized to create XXXXXXX instance.

I assigned CBO to a business role, the custom communication scenario along with communication arrangement is in place. I tested already the service (metadata) and the user is not locked.

Here´s the error sent back from the backend:

```
2020 05 27 19:36:55#+00#ERROR#com.sap.cloud.extensibility.services.CockpitServiceImp##PHENRIQUE#https-jsse-nio-8041-exec-8#na#fzrl99axqb#csccapplication2#web#fzrl99axqb#na#na#na#na#Error building up cockpit. com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: The endpoint responded with HTTP error code 400.
You're not authorized to create CSCCOCKPIT instance.
Full error message: 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "SCBO_AUTHORIZATION/000",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "You\\u0027re not authorized to create CSCCOCKPIT instance."
    },
    "innererror": {
      "application": {
        "component_id": "BC-ESI-ESF-GW",
        "service_namespace": "/SAP/",
        "service_id": "YY1_CSCCOCKPIT_CDS",
        "service_version": "0001"
      },
      "transactionid": "338BDCAE69170270E005EC3E361F2498",
      "timestamp": "20200527193655.5607910",
      "Error_Resolution": {
        "SAP_Transaction": "For backend administrators: use ADT feed reader \\"SAP Gateway Error Log\\" or run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP Gateway hub system and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details",
        "SAP_Note": "See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1797736)"
      },
      "errordetails": [
        {
          "code": "SCBO_AUTHORIZATION/000",
          "message": "You\\u0027re not authorized to create CSCCOCKPIT instance.",
          "propertyref": "",
          "severity": "error",
          "transition": true,
          "target": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone give a clue on where could the issue be?

BR,

Pietro

Answer (score 1):

The error happened because all the fields in the custom business object in S/4Hana Cloud were set as "read-only".